# HttpRequestBase - How to print the request with all its data

Tags: java, http, tostring

I'm using HttpRequestBase and I want to log the request fully to a log file before using it.

The default toString returns only the request line and I want to print all the headers, parameters, request body etc...

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `HttpRequestBase` object (`HttpGet`, `HttpPost`, etc.) contains information about the headers, parameters, and the implementation class contains the body, but it's not actually serialized into a `String`. That happens when the `HttpClient` actually sends the request.

You can play with the http components [logging configuration](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html).

Or you can call the appropriate methods and do it yourself.

```
HttpRequestBase base = new HttpGet("www.google.com");
Header[] headers = base.getAllHeaders();
// iterate and print
```

For the body, you need to cast to your implementation class and get the `HttpEntity`, if it has one.

```
HttpEntity entity = ((HttpPost)base).getEntity(); // example
```

And print it (its `InputStream` content). **Note: That might consume the entity.**

Full example

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("www.google.com");
post.setHeader(new BasicHeader("User-Agent", "random client"));
HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity("yellaworld");
post.setEntity(entity);
Header[] headers = post.getAllHeaders();
String content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

System.out.println(post.toString());
for (Header header : headers) {
    System.out.println(header.getName() + ": " + header.getValue());
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println(content);
```

prints

```
POST www.google.com HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: random client

yellaworld
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "That might consume the entity" ?

Comment: @AlokMishra See [here](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContent()). The entities can't always be read more than once.

Answer (score 4):

This works

```
private void printRequest() {
            System.out.println("receive " + httpRequest.getMethod() +" notification for "+ httpRequest.getRequestURI());


            System.out.println(" \n\n Headers");

            Enumeration headerNames = httpRequest.getHeaderNames();
            while(headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
                String headerName = (String)headerNames.nextElement();
                System.out.println(headerName + " = " + httpRequest.getHeader(headerName));
            }

            System.out.println("\n\nParameters");

            Enumeration params = httpRequest.getParameterNames();
            while(params.hasMoreElements()){
                String paramName = (String)params.nextElement();
                System.out.println(paramName + " = " + httpRequest.getParameter(paramName));
            }

            System.out.println("\n\n Row data");
            System.out.println(extractPostRequestBody(httpRequest));
        }

        static String extractPostRequestBody(HttpServletRequest request) {
            if ("POST".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
                Scanner s = null;
                try {
                    s = new Scanner(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
            }
            return "";
        }
```